# MVVM Validation in UWP

Tags: c#, validation, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

In the last week I've been trying to apply MVVM Pattern to Universal Windows Plataform, in  the most elegant possible way, that means apply SOLID principles and some popular design patterns.

I've been trying to reproduce this exercise from this link:
http://www.sullinger.us/blog/2014/7/4/custom-object-validation-in-winrt

Also the link is for Windows 8 apps it also applies to Windows 10 apps according to MSDN answer at this forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/05690519-1937-4e3b-aa12-c6ca89e57266/uwp-what-is-the-recommended-approach-for-data-validation-in-uwp-windows-10?forum=wpdevelop

Let me show you my classes, this is my view my final view:

```
<Page
x:Class="ValidationTestUWP.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ValidationTestUWP"
xmlns:conv="using:ValidationTestUWP.Converters"
xmlns:viewmodels="using:ValidationTestUWP.ViewModel"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:AccountCreationViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <conv:ValidationMessageConverter x:Key="ValidationMessageConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">

    <!-- E-Mail address input -->
    <TextBlock Text="Email"
               Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
    <TextBox x:Name="EmailTextBox"
             Margin="0 5 0 0"
             MinWidth="200"
             Text="{Binding Path=AppUser.Email, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    <!--We now have one more thing to do. We need to update our XAML. 
        The Error TextBlocks will now bind to the ValidationMessages property within the model,
        using an index matching the property they are bound to.-->
    <TextBlock x:Name="EmailValidationErrorTextBlock"
               Text="{Binding AppUser.ValidationMessages[Email], Converter={StaticResource ValidationMessageConverter}}"
               Foreground="Red" />

        <!-- Password input -->
    <TextBlock Text="Password"
               Margin="0 30 0 0"
               Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="PasswordTextBox"
             Margin="0 5 0 0"
             MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=EmailTextBox, Path=MinWidth}"
             Text="{Binding Path=AppUser.ValidationMessages[Password], Converter={StaticResource ValidationMessageConverter}}"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="PasswordValidationToShortErrorTextBlock"
               Text="{Binding PasswordToShortError}"
               Foreground="Red" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="PasswordValidationToLongErrorTextBlock"
               Text="{Binding PasswordToLongError}"
               Foreground="Red" />

    <!-- Login command button -->
    <Button Content="Create Account"
            Margin="0,10, 0, 0"
            Command="{Binding CreateAccount}"/>
</StackPanel>
</Page>
```

My model end up looking like this: (also I'm adding explanation of this classes within the comments in the classes.)

```
public class User : ValidatableBase
{
    private string email = string.Empty;

    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set
        {
            email = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Email");
        }
    }

    private string password = string.Empty;

    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set
        {
            password = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }

    /*Now that we are inheriting from our base class, we need to implement the required Validate() method.
     * In order to keep with the Single-Responsibility-Principle, we will invoke other methods from within
     * the Validate() method. 
     * Since we have to validate multiple properties, we should have each property validation be contained 
     * within it's own method. This makes it easier to test.*/
    public override void Validate()
    {
        ValidatePassword("Password");
        //base.OnPropertyChanged("Password");
        ValidateEmail("Email");
        //base.OnPropertyChanged("Email");

        // Passing in an empty string will cause the ValidatableBase indexer to be hit.
        // This will let the UI refresh it's error bindings.
        base.OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }

    /*Here we just invoke a ValidatePassword and ValidateEmail method. 
     * When we are done, we notify any observers that the entire object has changed by not specifying a property name
     * in the call to OnPropertyChanged. 
     * This lets the observers (in this case, the View) know its bindings need to be refreshed.*/
    private IValidationMessage ValidateEmail(string property)
    {
        const string emailAddressEmptyError = "Email address can not be blank.";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Email))
        {
            var msg = new ValidationErrorMessage(emailAddressEmptyError);
            return msg;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private IValidationMessage ValidatePassword(string property)
    {
        const string passwordToShortError = "Password must a minimum of 8 characters in length.";
        const string passwordToLongError = "Password must not exceed 16 characters in length.";
        if (this.Password.Length < 8)
        {
            var msg = new ValidationErrorMessage(passwordToShortError);
            return msg;
        }
        if (this.Password.Length > 16)
        {
            var msg = new ValidationErrorMessage(passwordToLongError);
            return msg;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
/*View Model 
 * 
 * Next, we need to revise our View Model.
 * We will delete all of the error properties within it, along with the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.
 * We will only need the AppUser property and the ICommand implementation.*/
public class AccountCreationViewModel
{
    public AccountCreationViewModel()
    {
        this.AppUser = new User();
        CreateAccount = new MyCommand(CreateUserAccount);
    }

    private User appUser;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };
    public MyCommand CreateAccount { get; set; }

    public User AppUser
    {
        get { return appUser; }
        set
        {
            appUser = value;
        }
    }

    private void CreateUserAccount()
    {
        AppUser.Validate();

        if (AppUser.HasValidationMessageType<ValidationErrorMessage>())
        {
            return;
        }
        // Create the user
        // ......
    }

    /*Now, when you run the app and enter an invalid Email or Password,
     * the UI will automatically inform you of the validation errors when you press the Create Account button. 
     * If you ever need to add more Email validation (such as the proper email format) 
     * or more Password validation (such as not allowing specific characters) you can do so without needing
     * to modify your View Model or your View.
     * 
     * If you need to add a whole new property to the Model, with validation, you can. You don't need to modify
     * your View Model, you only need to add a TextBlock to the View to display the validation.*/
}
```

Also I've applied a RelayCommand Pattern:

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    Action _TargetExecuteMethod;
    Func<bool> _TargetCanExecuteMethod;

    public MyCommand(Action executeMethod)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
    }

    public MyCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
        _TargetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    /*Beware - should use weak references if command instance lifetime 
    is longer than lifetime of UI objects that get hooked up to command*/
    // Prism commands solve this in their implementation public event 
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_TargetCanExecuteMethod != null)
            return _TargetCanExecuteMethod();

        if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        /*This sintax use the null*/
        _TargetExecuteMethod?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

This is where the fun begins, I'll introduce the ValidatableBase created at the blog I showed you earlier:

```
public abstract class ValidatableBase : IValidatable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /*Our initial class contains the Dictionary that will hold our validation messages. 
     * Next, we implement the read-only property required by our interface.*/
    private Dictionary<string, List<IValidationMessage>> _validationMessages = 
        new Dictionary<string, List<IValidationMessage>>();

    /*The call to OnPropertyChanged will let the UI know that this collection has changed. 
     * This in most cases won't be used since the collection is read-only, but since it is going in to a base class,
     * we want to provide support for that.*/
    public Dictionary<string, List<IValidationMessage>> ValidationMessages
    {
        get { return _validationMessages; }
        set
        {
            _validationMessages = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ValidationMessages");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    /*our base class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged method, 
     * so we will remove it from our model and put the implementation in to our base class.*/
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    /*In this method, we check if the collection contains a Key matching the property supplied.
     * If it does, then we check it's values to see if any of them match the Type specified in < T>.
     * This lets you do something like
     * 
     * HasValidationMessageType< ValidationErrorMessage>("Email");
     * 
     * to check if the model has a validation error on the email property.*/
    public bool HasValidationMessageType<T>(string property = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property))
        {
            bool result = _validationMessages.Values.Any(collection =>
                collection.Any(msg => msg is T));
            return result;
        }

        return _validationMessages.ContainsKey(property);
    }

    /*In this method we create a new collection if the key doesn't exist yet,
     * we then double check to ensure this validation message does not already exist in the collection.
     * If not, we add it.*/
    public void AddValidationMessage(IValidationMessage message, string property = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property))
        {
            return;
        }

        // If the key does not exist, then we create one.
        if (!_validationMessages.ContainsKey(property))
        {
            _validationMessages[property] = new List<IValidationMessage>();
        }

        if (_validationMessages[property].Any(msg => msg.Message.Equals(message.Message) || msg == message))
        {
            return;
        }

        _validationMessages[property].Add(message);
    }

    /*Here we just check if there is any message for the supplied Key and remove it.
     * At the moment, this does not do any Type checking to see if there is more 
     * than one Type of object (Warning and Error) in the collection with the same message.
     * The method just removes the first thing it finds and calls it good.*/
    public void RemoveValidationMessage(string message, string property = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!_validationMessages.ContainsKey(property))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (_validationMessages[property].Any(msg => msg.Message.Equals(message)))
        {
            // Remove the error from the key's collection.
            _validationMessages[property].Remove(
                _validationMessages[property].FirstOrDefault(msg => msg.Message.Equals(message)));
        }
    }

    /*We just check if a key exists that matches the property name and then clear out its messages contents
     * and remove the key from the Dictionary.*/
    public void RemoveValidationMessages(string property = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!_validationMessages.ContainsKey(property))
        {
            return;
        }

        _validationMessages[property].Clear();
        _validationMessages.Remove(property);
    }

    /*Finally, we finish implementing the interface by building the ValidateProperty method.
     * In this method, we just invoke the delegate we are provided, and accept a IValidationMessage object in return.
     * If the return value is not null, then we add it to the ValidationMessages collection.
     * If it is null, then we can assume that the validation passed and there are no issues.
     * Since that is the case, we remove it from the validation collection.*/
    public IValidationMessage ValidateProperty(Func<string, IValidationMessage> validationDelegate,
        string failureMessage, string propertyName = "")
    {
        IValidationMessage result = validationDelegate(failureMessage);
        if (result != null)
        {
            this.AddValidationMessage(result, propertyName);
        }
        else
        {
            this.RemoveValidationMessage(failureMessage, propertyName);
        }

        return result;
    }

    /*We have satisfied the requirements of the IValidatable interface, but there is one more method
     * we need to add to the base class. This will let us group all of our property validations in to a single call.
     * 
     * We mark it as abstract, since the base class has nothing to validate, 
     * and we want to force any object that inherits from the base class to implement the method. 
     * If you don't want to do this, you can opt out of in your code. Not everyone needs to have this feature,
     * thus the reason why it was left out of the interface.*/
    public abstract void Validate();
}
```

Lastly this are my interfaces:

```
//The first thing I did was created an interface that all models needing validation would be required to implement. 
public interface IValidatable
{
    /*This is a read-only property, that will contain all of our validation messages. 
     * The property has a Key typed to a string, which will be the Models property name. 
     * The value is a collection of IValidationMessage objects (We will discuss what the IValidationMessage is later).
     * The idea being that for each property in the model, we can store more than 1 error.*/
    Dictionary<string, List<IValidationMessage>> ValidationMessages { get; }

    /*This method is used to add a validation message to the ValidationMessages collection.
     * The property will be assigned as the Key, with the message being added as the value.*/
    void AddValidationMessage(IValidationMessage message, string property = "");

    /*Just like we can add a validation message, we will provide ourselves with the ability to remove it.*/
    void RemoveValidationMessage(string message, string property = "");

    /*We can use this method to completely clear out all validation messages in one shot for a single property.*/
    void RemoveValidationMessages(string property = "");

    /*This method will return true if the object has validation messages matching <T> and false if it does not.*/
    bool HasValidationMessageType<T>(string property = "");

    /*This method can be called to actually perform validation on a property within the object and 
     * build the collection of errors. The arguments require a method delegate that returns an IValidationMessage object.
     * This is how the validation becomes reusable. Each individual object can pass in a method delegate that performs
     * the actual validation. The IValidatable implementation will take the results and determine if it must go in to
     * the ValidationMessages collection or not.*/
    IValidationMessage ValidateProperty(Func<string, IValidationMessage> validationDelegate, 
        string failureMessage,
        string propertyName = "");
}

/*The idea with this, is that we can create objects that implement this interface,
 * but containing different types of messages. For instance, in this post, we will create a ValidationErrorMessage
 * and a ValidationWarningMessage. You could go on and create any kind of messaging you want and use it
 * for binding to the View.*/
public interface IValidationMessage
{
    string Message { get; }
}
```

This is my Converter:

```
/*The idea with this, is that we can create objects that implement this interface,
 * but containing different types of messages. For instance, in this post, we will create a ValidationErrorMessage
 * and a ValidationWarningMessage. You could go on and create any kind of messaging you want and use it
 * for binding to the View.*/
public interface IValidationMessage
{
    string Message { get; }
}
```

and finally my ValidationErrorMessages:

```
 /*Before we end the post, I will show you two implementations of the IValidationMessage.
 * They both do the same thing, but are Typed differently so that you can segregate your messages by Type.
 * This gives more flexibility that using an Enum.
 * 
 * First is the Error validation message.*/
public class ValidationErrorMessage : IValidationMessage
{
    public ValidationErrorMessage() : this(string.Empty)
    { }

    public ValidationErrorMessage(string message)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public string Message { get; private set; }
}
```

Now every time I run the code like this code in the example shown at Sullinger Blog I get a Exception:

> **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:** 'The text associated with this error code could not be found.

I'm using VS2017 I'm trying to apply MVVM pattern to Validation in UWP, of course I could do validation on my ViewModel for every Field but it implies that I'll have to write Validation for every view I created and as far as I see in this example, this could save me tons of code.

Does anyone understand what is wrong with this code?

I don't want to use tools like MVVM Light or MVVM Cross or Prism this is purely Custom MVVM on UWP.

Comment: _"...of course I could do validation on my ViewModel for every Field but it implies that i'll have to write Validation for every view..."_ - what I tend to do as use **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** on the **M** and perform validation there.  The **VM** merely calls a helper function to ask the **M** to validate itself.   Using this approach allows for greater code re-use

Comment: well what i meant by that at sullinger blog is that he show three approaches, first one is the code-behind approach, the second approach is the one i was trying to describe where he performs Validation on the model and set the viewmodel who also returns the result to the view.
The third approach is the one i havent been able to solve I dont understand why am I getting this exception, could you help me?

Comment: I would recommend that you avoid asking for someone to take your work and finish it - I have removed that from your question. Stack Overflow is for obtaining assistance so you can complete your project; it is not an ordering service for free work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the recommendation, but almost every question i've done i ended up resolving it by myself and always publish the answer. Anyways my main issue is to understand why am i getting the reflection exception. I know that the string.empty property of the example is crashing the program. But if I use property names UI isnt update. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Finally I was able to make this code work, it has some fixes but I was able to understand it and also solve it on my own, before I publish my answer because i have two answers for this problem, I'll like to apologize to the community, I didnt want to ask for help so that you could do it for me, it wasnt my intention, if it looked like that, I'm sorry, i'll try to sound less needy.

Well down to the solution:

the main issue of the code I've published is in the abstract method Validate, since you gotta write your own validation for each field and also this is where you control the adding and removal of error messages, so I wrote a Validate Method like this one:

```
public override void Validate()
    {
        RemoveValidationMessages("Password");
        RemoveValidationMessages("Email");
        AddValidationMessage(ValidatePassword("Password"), "Password");
        AddValidationMessage(ValidateEmail("Email"), "Email");

        // Passing in an empty string will cause the ValidatableBase indexer to be hit.
        // This will let the UI refresh it's error bindings.
        base.OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }
```

As you can see I've always begin the method removing all message so that we do not add more than once message, since the addvalidation message doesnt allow you to repeat the same error message.
Then we use the AddValidationMessageMethod within the method we use our custom validate methods for password or email so that they return a message to add here in our custom methods was my issue, I return null to my message so everytime the converter was trigger it throwed the Exception I showed at my question.
So in order to solve it instead of returning null when textboxes had some text I returned the empty constructor of ValidationErrorMessages Class like this methods:

```
private IValidationMessage ValidateEmail(string property)
    {
        const string emailAddressEmptyError = "Email address can not be blank.";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Email))
        {
            var msg = new ValidationErrorMessage(emailAddressEmptyError);
            return msg;
        }

        return new ValidationErrorMessage();
    }

    private IValidationMessage ValidatePassword(string property)
    {
        const string passwordToShortError = "Password must a minimum of 8 characters in length.";
        const string passwordToLongError = "Password must not exceed 16 characters in length.";
        if (this.Password.Length < 8)
        {
            var msg = new ValidationErrorMessage(passwordToShortError);
            return msg;
        }
        if (this.Password.Length > 16)
        {
            var msg = new ValidationErrorMessage(passwordToLongError);
            return msg;
        }

        return new ValidationErrorMessage();
    }
```

This solve the problem of triggering the exception.
also you could leave this methods returning null but you would have to modify the converter so it checks the IValidationMessages Collection for null values.

it would look like this:

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (!(value is IEnumerable<IValidationMessage>))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var collection = value as IEnumerable<IValidationMessage>;
        if (!collection.Any())
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        if (collection.FirstOrDefault() == null)
        {
           return string.Empty;
        }           

        return collection.FirstOrDefault().Message;
    }
```

This way we can update our error messages for the fields and now guy you can have a working MVVM Validation Working Pattern for UWP. with a highly testable, maintainable and extensible app.

Hope this solution help for those digging at UWP.
Also there are some great articles from many different sources you could try sullinger blog which was the approach i'm adopting but also wintellect has an article i'll share the link here: http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jlikness/simple-validation-with-mvvm-for-windows-store-apps

this also work for UWP I've tested it but you gotta work it a bit more.
and jerry Nixon has a great article for UWP Validation too, his model is way more elegant than Sullinger this is the link for Nixon Validation: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-handling-validation-in-your.html

and he has the source code here: http://xaml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Blog/201406-Validation/App10/Common/ModelBase.cs

well hope this help someone else.
Any questions i'll be glad to help you too.